# Writing to log file doesent show walues

Tags: java, csv

i am haveing trouble when i try to write values to csv file, i only get default values. Inside add button action listener i have for loop that only shows default from column model set on top, and i dont have any ideas so please help.

edit: i have this values inside the food log and they are displayed correctly, but in log.csv they dont exist

```
    /*
     * Creating default model and adding labels for food nutrients
     */
    columnModel = new DefaultTableModel();

    columnModel.addColumn("Name");
    columnModel.addColumn("Unit Amount");
    columnModel.addColumn("Calories");
    columnModel.addColumn("Fat");
    columnModel.addColumn("Protein");
    columnModel.addColumn("Carbs");

    recordBoard = new JTable(columnModel);
    recordBoard.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(recordBoard.getPreferredSize());
    recordBoard.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    JTableHeader header = recordBoard.getTableHeader();
    add(header);
    add(recordBoard);

    JPanel logButton = new JPanel();
    logButton.setLayout(new BoxLayout(logButton, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    /*
     * Creating search text field for all foods
     */
    JLabel comboBoxLabel = new JLabel("Search all Foods: ", JLabel.RIGHT);
    csvFoods = new JComboBox();
    logButton.add(comboBoxLabel);
    logButton.add(csvFoods);

    /*
     * Creating new button for saveing food records
     */
    recordSave = new JButton("Add Food");
    recordSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            controller.addLogRow(String.valueOf(csvFoods.getSelectedItem()), columnModel);

            try {
                columnModel = (DefaultTableModel) recordBoard.getModel();
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File("log.csv"), true);
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                recordBoard.getTableHeader().setUI(null);;
                fw.write("\n");
                fw.write(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + ",");
                fw.write(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1 + ",");
                fw.write(cal.get(Calendar.DATE) + ",");
                fw.write("f" + ",");
                for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
                    fw.write(columnModel.getColumnName(i) + ",");
                }
                fw.write("\n");
                fw.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace(); 
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: The values doesn't appear or they appear with wrong value?

Comment: Are you sure you need `getColumnName(i)`? Columns names usually don't change...

Comment: Note that nowadays we read and write files using the newer API, called NIO. It revolves around the classes `Files`, `Paths` and `Path`. Reading and writing are one-liner there, without the need for try-catch and creating `FileWriter` and all that stuff. The `File` class is old, use the new methods.

Comment: This is image of my outputs, top is values shown in food log and they work correctly, and bottom one is csv and it has only date working as it is supposed to work.
https://imgur.com/a/R7nqt

Comment: You have to iterate over the number of rows in your table model, within each row iterate over all columsn, and use `getValueAt(row, column)` instead

Comment: @Nadir i have tried to use getValueAt but i dont think i have implemented it properly, can you please show me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the column names of the table, rather than the content itself.

To print the content, you should iterate over each row of data, and within each row, over each column:

```
for(int i = 0; i < columnModel.getRowCount(); i++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < columnModel.getColumnCount(); j++) {
       Object data = columnModel.getValueAt(i, j);
       // print to file
   }
}
```